# Legacy code mutates a const pointer. Any legitimate reason?

Tags: c++, casting, constants, undefined-behavior

I have some code that's accumulated a lot of cruft over many years. It has a class that looks like:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(int* data) : data_(data) { }

  Foo() : data_(nullptr) { }

  void loadFile(File* file);

private:
 const int* data_;
};

void Foo::loadFile(File* file) {
  file->loadToBuffer(const_cast<int**>(&data_));
}

void File::loadToBuffer(int** buf) {
  *buf = new int[1024];
  // Load the data...
}
```

I believe that the `const` member was originally used "properly" and initialized in the constructor, but over time other ways to initialize the object were added that didn't fit that pattern so the `const_cast` was used as a workaround. The actual class is very large (many thousands of lines) and the initialization is complicated enough that it's not possible to factor it out in a way that respects the `const`.

As far as I know this is undefined behavior, and so it should be killed with fire by removing the `const` qualifier on `data_`. But this code has been kicking around for a long time without causing any obvious problems, so I'm not sure if there's something I'm missing --- is this (mis)use of `const` ever acceptable, in theory or in practice? Are there any conceivable benefits to writing something like this, or is it just a happy accident that it hasn't broken yet?

Comment: `file->loadToBuffer(&const_cast<int*>(data_));` should not compile because you try to take the address of an l-value.

Comment: [Doesn't compile here](http://ideone.com/5qlvOa).  Or [here](http://rextester.com/CSG88929) using Visual C++ 2015.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I suppose that helps to uncover some of my confusion --- it was `const_cast<int**>(&data_)`. I was thinking of this like `&((int*)data_)` would be in C. Thanks for clearing that up. Fixed in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pointer to const int, it can point either to an int or to a const int

```
const int* data_;
```

You can change data_ (you can direct it to point to another int/const int)

You cannot change *data_ (you cannot change the pointed value)

When you do a static_cast on it, it is allowed ONLY if data_ points to an int without const. static_cast in case data_ points to const int would cause undefined behaviour.

So in this case the code is fine because data_ will only point to int (and not const int), either with Foo first constructor or in loadToBuffer.

Comment: All true, but the relevant part is the `&` in `&const_cast...`. You can't take the address of the returned value, it's not an object. Same bug as `int* ptr = &4;`

Comment: Well yes, but I'm not sure that's the relevant part. This can be easily solved by assigning the result of the const_cast in a local variable

Comment: If you assign it to a local variable, you wouldn't be modifying `Foo::data` anymore. Sure, you could first assign `Foo::data` to a local variable, then later assign it back, but why bother with the first step? Just create a local variable of the right type `int*tmp=nullptr`, don't cast anything, call `loadBuffer(&tmp)` and then assign `data = tmp`.(Implicit cast **to** `const`).

Comment: And that would fail because `LoadToBuffer` can't change that `int*`.

Comment: Right, sorry, well actually there's no need to take int** as parameter, you can just take an int* (which would still require a const_cast). even if you take a const int*, you can assign it with new int[4], since you can change the pointed value and you can point to non const

Comment: @gbehar: I expect `loadBuffer(&ptr)` may have been written to achieve semantics similar to `ptr = realloc(ptr, ...);`, but without requiring redundant specification of the pointer.  Having a single pointer argument avoids redundancy, but C++ lacks a way of saying an argument will be used to accept a pointer from the caller which will be used in const-consistent fashion and but will yield a pointer that the caller need not use in const-consistent fashion.